# Kubernetes ingress for dynamic URL

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am developing an application that allows users to play around in their own sandboxes with a finite life time. Conceptually, it can be thought as if users were playing games of Pong. Users can interact with a web interface hosted at main/ to start a game of Pong. Each game of Pong will exist in its own pod. Since each game has a finite lifetime, the pods are dynamically created on-demand (through the Kubernetes API) as Kubernetes jobs with a single pod. There is therefore a one-to-one relationship between games of Pong and pods. Up to this point I have it all figured out.

My problem is, how do I set up an ingress to map dynamically created URLs, for example main/game1, to the corresponding pods? That is, if a user starts a game through the main interface, I would like him to be redirected to the URL of the corresponding pod where his game is hosted.

I could pre-allocate a set of urls, check if they have active jobs, and redirect if they do not, but the does not scale well. I am thinking dynamically assigning URLs is a common pattern in Kubernetes, so there must be a standard way to do this. I have looked at using nginx-ingress, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: IMO you should do it on the server level, not the ingress

Comment: Since you're already using Kubernetes API, you can also process dynamically the Ingress resource adding or popping paths: this is definitely the best solution, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore the comment, I created for you a little demo on `minikube` providing a working *Ingress Class* controller (enabled via `minikube addons enable ingress`).

Replicating the multiple *Deployment* that simulates the games.

```
kubectl create deployment deployment-1 --image=nginxdemos/hello
kubectl create deployment deployment-2 --image=nginxdemos/hello
kubectl create deployment deployment-3 --image=nginxdemos/hello
kubectl create deployment deployment-4 --image=nginxdemos/hello
kubectl create deployment deployment-5 --image=nginxdemos/hello
```

Same for *Services* resources:

```
kubectl create service clusterip deployment-1 --tcp=80:80
kubectl create service clusterip deployment-2 --tcp=80:80
kubectl create service clusterip deployment-3 --tcp=80:80
kubectl create service clusterip deployment-4 --tcp=80:80
kubectl create service clusterip deployment-5 --tcp=80:80
```

Finally, it's time for the *Ingress* one but we have to be quite hacky since we don't have the subcommand `create` available.

```
for number in `seq 5`; do echo "
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deployment-$number
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
 rules:
 - host: hello-world.info
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /game$number
       backend:
         serviceName: deployment-$number
         servicePort: 80
" | kubectl create -f -; done
```

Now you have *Pod*, *Service* and *Ingress*: obviously, you have to replicate the same result using Kubernetes API but, as I suggested in the comment, you should create a *single* *Ingress* resource and update accordingly *Path* subkey in a dynamic way.

However, if you try to simulate the cURL call faking the `Host` header, you can see the working result:

```
# curl `minikube ip`/game2 -sH 'Host: hello-world.info'|grep -i server
<p><span>Server&nbsp;address:</span> <span>172.17.0.5:80</span></p>
<p><span>Server&nbsp;name:</span> <span>deployment-2-5b98b954f6-8g5fl</span></p>

# curl `minikube ip`/game4 -sH 'Host: hello-world.info'|grep -i server
<p><span>Server&nbsp;address:</span> <span>172.17.0.7:80</span></p>
<p><span>Server&nbsp;name:</span> <span>deployment-4-767ff76774-d2fgj</span></p>
```

You can see the *Pod* IP and name as well.

Comment: ops, noticed you can automate even more the Service and Deployment resource using a simple iteration using `seq` also there but... in the end, the Ingress part is the one you should really take care for this example!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Efrat Levitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10589890/efrat-levitan). It's not the task for ingress/kubernetes itself.

You need another application (different layer of abstraction) to distinguish where the traffic should be routed for example istio and [Routing rule for HTTP traffic](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-rule-for-http-traffic)  based on cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean an Nginx instance running as its pen service that can then route the traffic?

Comment: Not at all - in your example you need more sophisticated solution some central application managing/control the flow and triggering creation of the appropriate resource. Here is one of examples [Running Dedicated Game Servers in Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/running-dedicated-game-servers-in-kubernetes-engine)